Adjusting ggplot2 facet_wrap plot sizes based on number of rows
I am using ggplot2 in R to visualise data using facet_wrap(), and I would like to adjust the sizes of the graphs so that the graph with more rows (MF and CC in the example) appear larger and the one with fewer rows (BP) smaller. But that the size of the graph as a whole, does not change. This is an example of the data:
df <- data.frame(
  'Seq ratio' = runif(15, min = 0, max = 0.5),
  'feature' = stringi::stri_rand_strings(15, 1, pattern = "[A-F]"),
  'Seq count' = c(8, 10, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 7, 15, 15, 15),
  'adj. P value' = c(0.012609566, 0.012609566, 0.033278332, 0.021875357, 
  0.021875357,0.003216359, 0.003216359, 0.003216359, 0.030076544, 0.017188404, 
  0.003216359, 0.047018661, 0.002584020, 0.002584020, 0.002584020),
  'cluster' = c('Cluster 1', 'Cluster 1', 'Cluster 1', 'Cluster 1', 
  'Cluster 1', 'Cluster 2', 'Cluster 2', 'Cluster 2', 'Cluster 2', 
  'Cluster 3', 'Cluster 3', 'Cluster 4', 'Cluster 4', 'Cluster 4', 'Cluster 4'), 
  'Category' = c('MF', 'MF', 'CC', 'MF', 'CC', 'BP', 'BP', 'BP',
   'BP', 'MF', 'MF', 'BP', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC'))

ggplot(aes(seq_ratio, feature, size = seq_count, colour = adj_p_value)) +
  facet_wrap(~category, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_point() +
  ylab(NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 5) +
  scale_size(name = "Seq count", limits = c(0, 15))



facet_grid offers the ability to scale the facets depending on their scales.
ggplot(df, aes(Seq.ratio, feature, size = Seq.count, colour = adj..P.value)) +
  facet_grid(vars(Category), scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") +
  geom_point() +
  ylab(NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 5) +
  scale_size(name = "Seq count", limits = c(0, 15))


